# Fatal Error Main

Tags: android, runtime-error

Im beginner on android app. I currently do an app for student in my college.

At first i start this CGPA calculator first at MainActivity.
It work fine then i continue to do it. 
but my boss request me to do a navigate page before this page.

then i found out i need another MainActivity is the first page that android will start up.
i try to change something in the Manifest but it don't work

then i create a new project and build the navigate page first at MainActivity.
i create another class file name Calculator and i copy then whole code and put inside.

Now i use intent to navigate from MainActivity to Calculator class and it will crash.
But it work on other page. so i suspect it somethings wrong on this class.
i found out at the log it say Fatal Error Main when i try to click on the button navigate to calculator.

Please help me to have a look. 
Sorry i have a bad language.

This is my MainActivity Intent code

```
public void calc(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Calculator.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my calculator.class

```
package com.example.mobileassignment;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
public class Calculator extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

    EditText editDec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastSem);
    setSpinner();
    sGrade1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

Spinner sGrade1,sGrade2,sGrade3,sGrade4,sGrade5,sCredit1,sCredit2,sCredit3,sCredit4,sCredit5;
Double result1,result2,result3,result4,result5,cresult1,cresult2,cresult3,cresult4,cresult5;
String ans;


public void setSpinner(){
    sGrade1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGrade1);
    sGrade2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGrade2);
    sGrade3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGrade3);
    sGrade4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGrade4);
    sGrade5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinGrade5);

    sCredit1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCredit1);
    sCredit2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCredit2);
    sCredit3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCredit3);
    sCredit4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCredit4);
    sCredit5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinCredit5);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterGrade = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.gradeList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterGrade.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCredit = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.creditList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapterCredit.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    sGrade1.setAdapter(adapterGrade);
    sGrade2.setAdapter(adapterGrade);
    sGrade3.setAdapter(adapterGrade);
    sGrade4.setAdapter(adapterGrade);
    sGrade5.setAdapter(adapterGrade);
    sCredit1.setAdapter(adapterCredit);
    sCredit2.setAdapter(adapterCredit);
    sCredit3.setAdapter(adapterCredit);
    sCredit4.setAdapter(adapterCredit);
    sCredit5.setAdapter(adapterCredit);



}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
  }


  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

  }

  public double checkPoint(String sub1){
      double res = 0;
      if(sub1.equals("A")){
            res = 4.0;
        }else if(sub1.equals("A-")){
            res = 3.75;
        }else if(sub1.equals("B+")){
            res = 3.5;
        }else if(sub1.equals("B")){
            res = 3.0;
        }else if(sub1.equals("B-")){
            res = 2.75;
        }else if(sub1.equals("C+")){
            res = 2.5;
        }else if(sub1.equals("C")){
            res = 2.0;
        }else if(sub1.equals("C-")){
            res = 1.75;
        }else if(sub1.equals("D")){
            res = 1.0;
        }else if(sub1.equals("F")){
            res = 0.0;
        }else if(sub1.equals("-")){
            res = 0.0;
        }else{
            res = 123;
        }

      return res;
  }

  public double checkCredit(String cre){
      double resu = 0;
      if(cre.equals("1")){
          resu = 1.0;
      }else if(cre.equals("2")){
          resu = 2.0;
      }else if(cre.equals("3")){
          resu = 3.0;
      }else if(cre.equals("4")){
          resu = 4.0;
      }else if(cre.equals("5")){
          resu = 5.0;
      }else if(cre.equals("-")){
          resu = 0.0;
      }else {
          resu = 123;
      }

      return resu;
  }

public void calculateGPA(View view) {

    sGrade1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sGrade5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sCredit5.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    result1 = checkPoint((String)sGrade1.getSelectedItem());
    result2 = checkPoint((String)sGrade2.getSelectedItem());
    result3 = checkPoint((String)sGrade3.getSelectedItem());
    result4 = checkPoint((String)sGrade4.getSelectedItem());
    result5 = checkPoint((String)sGrade5.getSelectedItem());

    cresult1 = checkCredit((String)sCredit1.getSelectedItem());
    cresult2 = checkCredit((String)sCredit2.getSelectedItem());
    cresult3 = checkCredit((String)sCredit3.getSelectedItem());
    cresult4 = checkCredit((String)sCredit4.getSelectedItem());
    cresult5 = checkCredit((String)sCredit5.getSelectedItem());

    EditText editDec = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLastSem);

    double lastSem = 0;
    if(editDec.getText().toString().matches("")||editDec.getText().toString().matches(".") ){

    }else{
//      lastSem = Double.parseDouble(editDec.getText().toString());
    }


    double totalcre = cresult1 + cresult2 + cresult3 + cresult4 + cresult5;
    double total = (result1 * cresult1) + (result2 * cresult2) + (result3 * cresult3) + (result4 * cresult4) + (result5 * cresult5);
    double gpa = total / totalcre;

    if(editDec.getText().toString().matches("")||editDec.getText().toString().matches(".") ){
        lastSem = gpa;
    }

    double cgpa = (gpa + lastSem) / 2;

    //Toast.makeText(this, ans +"" + result1 +""+ cresult1 +""+ result2 +""+ cresult2 +""+ result3 +""+ cresult3  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Your GPA : " + gpa + "\n" + "Your CGPA : " + cgpa , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

This is the Log i found out.

```
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3725)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4262)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17351)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3720)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    ... 11 more
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mobileassignment/com.example.mobileassignment.MainActivity$Calculator}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1556)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1431)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3446)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3407)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3617)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3585)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    at com.example.mobileassignment.MainActivity.calc(MainActivity.java:47)
08-13 21:43:55.925: E/AndroidRuntime(11192):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mobileassignment/com.example.mobileassignment.MainActivity$Calculator}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

means that you haven't declared Calculator Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity

        android:name=".Calculator " >

    </activity>
```